# How to use 0 as a acceptable number in RShiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to find a workaround, but couldnt get any solution...
Have anybody a idea, how I can use the number 0 as a acceptable number?

Because everytime then I try to set the value to zero, my ShinyApp just thinks its a NA value and does nothing with it...

## I use the numericInput function as follow:

```
numericInput(
              inputId = "a",
              label = NULL,
              value = NA, #also tried NULL, but same problem
```

anyone?

## Edit:

### My Ui.R:

```
div(class = "row",
    useShinyjs(),

    tags$div(
      HTML(
        "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>
                MathJax.Hub.Config({
                tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}
                });
                </script>
                "
      )
    ),
    div(
      class = "column",
      column(
        4,
        style = "background-color: #E8E8E8",
        br(),
        ##Titel
        div(style = "display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; text-align:center; width: 100%;color:#4c6586;font-size:30px;",
            strong(HTML("<u>Rechteckverteilung</u>"))),
        br(),
        br(),
        HTML("<center><h4><b>Parameter:</b></h4></center>"),
        HTML("<center><i>Bitte mindestens 2 Parameter eingeben:</i></center>"),
        hr(style="border-color: white;"),

        withMathJax(),

        ##Input-Boxen Zeile 1
        div(
          id = "form_sg",

          div(
            style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 200px;",
            strong(HTML("$a$ = Minimum")),
            numericInput(
              inputId = "sg_a",
              NULL,
              value = 0, #workaround damit 0 klappt
              width = 80
            ),
            bsTooltip(id = "sg_a",
                      title = "zB die untere Grenze. a muss kleiner als b sein!")
          ),
          div(
            style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 200px;",
            strong(HTML("$b$ = Maximum")),
            numericInput(
              inputId = "sg_b",
              NULL,
              value = NULL,
              width = 80
            ),
            bsTooltip(id = "sg_b",
                      title = "zB die obere Grenze. b muss groesser als a sein!")
          ),
          br(),

          div(
            style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 200px;",
            strong(HTML("$\\mu$ = Erwartungswert")),
            numericInput(
              inputId = "sg_e",
              NULL,
              value = NULL,
              width = 80
            ),
            bsTooltip(id = "sg_e",
                      title = "zB erwartete Wartezeit auf den Bus")
          ),
          br(),

          div(
            style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 200px;",
            strong(HTML("$f(x)$ = Wert der Dichtefunktion")),
            numericInput(
              inputId = "sg_fx",
              NULL,
              value = NULL,
              width = 80
            ),
            bsTooltip(id = "sg_fx",
                      title = "Falls der Wert der Dichtefunktion gegeben ist")
          ),
          br(),
          hr(style="border-color: white;"),
          HTML("<center><h4><b>Wahrscheinlichkeiten:</b></h4></center>"),
          br(),

        ),

        br(),

        actionButton("submit_sg", "Berechnen",
                     style = "color: #ffffff; background-color:#4c6586; border-color:#000;"),
        actionButton("reset_sg", "Reset",
                     style = "color: #ffffff; background-color:#4c6586; border-color:#000;"),
        br(),
        br()
      ),



      div(class = "column",
          column(
            8,
            tabsetPanel(
              tabPanel(
                "Ergebnisse",
                mainPanel(
                  hidden(
                    div(
                      id = "results_sg",

                      br(),
                      uiOutput("sg1"),
                      tags$head(tags$style("#sg1{color: white;font-size: 0px;}")),

                      htmlOutput("sg_Allgemein"),

                      uiOutput("sg2"),
                      tags$head(tags$style("#sg2{color: white;font-size: 0px;}"))
                    )
                  )
                )
              )

            )
          ))
    ))
```

### Server.R

```
div(
  observeEvent(input$submit_sg, {
    show("results_sg")
  }),
  
  observeEvent(input$reset_sg, {
    reset("form_sg")
    hide("results_sg")
  }),
  
  
  
  #Reihenfolge:
  #Erst htmlOutput, dann renderText, dann htmlOutput, dann renderText
  
  #Allgemein ----
  
  #Allgemeine-Tabelle: a,b , E(X), V(X), SD(X), Q, f(x),F(x), 
  
  #muss angezeigt werden, damit mathjax klappt. Wird aber farbe weiß sein
  output$sg1 <- renderUI({
    withMathJax(paste0(
      "$P$",
      input$sg_a,input$sg_b,input$sg_e,input$sg_fx))
    }),
  
  output$sg_Allgemein <- renderText({
    #falls a+b, fx+a, fx+b, mu+a, mu+b gegeben, blende Tabelle ein
    
    req( 
      (input$sg_a & input$sg_b)  | (input$sg_fx & input$sg_a) |
        (input$sg_fx & input$sg_b) | (input$sg_e & input$sg_a)  |
        (input$sg_e & input$sg_b)
    )
    
    at  <- input$sg_a 
    bt  <- input$sg_b
    fxt <- input$sg_fx
    et  <- input$sg_e
    
    #Falls a und b gegeben:
    if(!is.na(at & bt)) {
      a  <- at
      b  <- bt
      e <- (a+b)/2
      var <- ((b-a)^2)/12
      sd <- sqrt(var)
    }
    #Falls fx und a gegeben:
    if(!is.na(fxt & at)) {
      a  <- at
      fx <- fxt
      b  <- (1/fx) + a
      e <- (a+b)/2
      var <- ((b-a)^2)/12
      sd <- sqrt(var)
    }
    #Falls fx und b gegeben:
    if(!is.na(fxt & bt)) {
      b  <- bt
      fx <- fxt
      a <- (-1/fx) + b
      e <- (a+b)/2
      var <- ((b-a)^2)/12
      sd <- sqrt(var)
    }
    #Falls ew und a gegeben:
    if(!is.na(et & at)) {
      a  <- at
      e  <- et
      b <- 2*e - a
      var <- ((b-a)^2)/12
      sd <- sqrt(var)
    }
    #Falls ew und b gegeben:
    if(!is.na(et & bt)) {
      b  <- bt
      e  <- et
      a <- 2*e - b
      var <- ((b-a)^2)/12
      sd <- sqrt(var)
    }

    #Tabelle
    sg_Tabelle <- data.frame(
      Eigenschaften = c(
        "$a$",
        "$b$",
        "$\\mu_{X} = E(X)$",
        "$\\sigma_{X}^2 = V(X)$",
        "$\\sigma_{X} = \\sqrt{V(X)}$"
      ),
      Werte = c(
        round(c(
          a,b,e,var,sd),4)
      )
    )
    
    tab_1 <- kbl(
      format = "html",
      sg_Tabelle,
      caption = p(strong("Eigenschaften:"),
                  style = "color:#4c6586; font-size:18px;"),
      escape = FALSE
    )
    kable_styling(tab_1, bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"))
    
  }),
  
  #muss angezeigt werden, damit mathjax klappt. Wird aber farbe weiß sein
  output$sg2 <- renderUI({
    withMathJax(paste0(
      "$P$",
      input$sg_a,input$sg_b,input$sg_e,input$sg_fx
      ))
    })
)
```

### app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(knitr)
library(shinyBS)
library(kableExtra)
library(plotly)
library(shinyjs)


runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(#Navigationsseiten:
    shinyUI(navbarPage(
      "Statistik II",
      navbarMenu(
        "Zufallsverteilungen",
        tabPanel(
          "Geometrische Verteilung",
          source("ui_test2.R")$value
        ),
      )
    ))),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    #Zufallsverteilungen:
    source("server_test2.R", local = TRUE)
  }
))
```

Comment: To which function is he `numericaInput` sent as an input then ?

Comment: Can you post a MRE? The code you have posted does not show the problem since it accepts zero. We need to see the code that does not react to the change in value to zero, in other words we need to see how "nothing happens" in your app.

Comment: I have added a MRE, sry that I missed it at the beginning

Comment: to calculate the values, the user have to input "a" and "b" and press "Berechnen" (sry, its in german rn).... if you select a and b < or> 0, there is no problem. But if e.g. a is 0, than the output resets and I dont know why... because it should use the 0 as a acceptable value

Comment: btw, if I type 0.000001 for e.g. a it does work and show a = 0 in the table, but thats pretty laborious..

Comment: First problem: `req((input$sg_a & input$sg_b))` will be `FALSE` when either or both are zero. For instance, `req((0 & 1))` will evaluate `req(FALSE)` which will seems like "nothing happens" as it does not go through. Second problem: is.na checks objects, use `if (!is.na(at) & !is.na(bt))` not `if (is.na(at & bt))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an MRE to debug the app. It attempts to solve the problem by not using `req` at the beginning and instead check if the computed variables exist right before you build your table.

```
library(shiny)            

ui <- basicPage(
numericInput(
  inputId = "sg_a",
  "sg_a",
  value = NULL, #workaround damit 0 klappt
  width = 80
),
numericInput(
  inputId = "sg_b",
  "sg_b",
  value = NULL,
  width = 80
),
numericInput(
  inputId = "sg_e",
  "sg_e",
  value = NULL,
  width = 80
),
numericInput(
  inputId = "sg_fx",
  "sg_fx",
  value = NULL,
  width = 80
),
actionButton("submit_sg", "Berechnen"),
actionButton("reset_sg", "Reset"),
verbatimTextOutput("sg1"),
verbatimTextOutput("sg_Allgemein")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$sg1 <- renderPrint({
    vars <- c(input$sg_a,input$sg_b,input$sg_e,input$sg_fx)
    print(vars)
  })
  
  output$sg_Allgemein <- renderPrint({
    #falls a+b, fx+a, fx+b, mu+a, mu+b gegeben, blende Tabelle ein
    
    at  <- input$sg_a 
    bt  <- input$sg_b
    fxt <- input$sg_fx
    et  <- input$sg_e
    
    #Falls a und b gegeben:
    if(!is.na(at) & !is.na(bt)) {
      print("Falls a und b gegeben")
      a  <- at
      b  <- bt
      e <- (a+b)/2
      var <- ((b-a)^2)/12
      sd <- sqrt(var)
    }
    #Falls fx und a gegeben:
    if(!is.na(fxt) & !is.na(at)) {
      print("Falls fx und a gegeben")
      a  <- at
      fx <- fxt
      b  <- (1/fx) + a
      e <- (a+b)/2
      var <- ((b-a)^2)/12
      sd <- sqrt(var)
    }
    #Falls fx und b gegeben:
    if(!is.na(fxt) & !is.na(bt)) {
      print("Falls fx und b gegeben")
      b  <- bt
      fx <- fxt
      a <- (-1/fx) + b
      e <- (a+b)/2
      var <- ((b-a)^2)/12
      sd <- sqrt(var)
    }
    #Falls ew und a gegeben:
    if(!is.na(et) & !is.na(at)) {
      print("Falls ew und a gegeben")
      a  <- at
      e  <- et
      b <- 2*e - a
      var <- ((b-a)^2)/12
      sd <- sqrt(var)
    }
    #Falls ew und b gegeben:
    if(!is.na(et) & !is.na(bt)) {
      print("Falls ew und b gegebe")
      b  <- bt
      e  <- et
      a <- 2*e - b
      var <- ((b-a)^2)/12
      sd <- sqrt(var)
    }
    
    if (exists("e") &
        exists("var") &
        exists("sd")) {
      # build table here
      vars <- c(a,b,e,var,sd)
      print(vars)
    }
    
  })
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```